# SharePoint increment number to existing list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have a issue I am hoping to find out if it is even possible to fix. We had a SharePoint list that became corrupted and would not accept inserted code. I recreated the list and copied all the info over but did not realize one of the fields was using the Incremental ID field on new entries. So each new entry this field would automatically add the next number.

This field is a number field, is it possible to add a way to continue using the number increment on new entries? Now that it was moved to a new table I cant seem to find a way to start a process to keep increasing the number by one automatically.

I would just rebuild the column but it is a lookup on many other lists.

It sounds like something easy to fix but have not found a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There should be an ID field that automatically increments with each new item added.

Comment: agree with @Robbert how this field is incremented ? Anyway you can write a simple event handler (or workflow) to retrieve the ID value after post and put into this field.